# @OneToOne en Spring

Tags: mysql, spring

Como puedo hacer para que se guarden los datos relacionados?se guardan en la bd pero no relacionados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Metodo en CustomerController.java

```
@PostMapping("/customer")
public Customer postCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) {

    User user= new  User(customer.getUser().getUserName(),
customer.getUser().getPassword() 
 ,customer.getUser().getEmail());

    Customer _customer = new Customer();
    User _user = new User();

    _customer.setUser(_user);
    _user.setCustomer(_customer);

     _user = usuarioRepository.save(new User(user.getUserName(),user.getPassword(),user.getEmail()));

    _customer = customerRepository.save(new Customer(customer.getName(),customer.getAge()));

    return _customer;
}
```

user.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(name="userName")
private String userName;

@Column(name="email")
private String email;

@Column(name="password")
private String password;

@Column(name="logged")
private boolean logged;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
private Customer customer;


public User() {

}

public User(String userName,String password,String email) {
    this.userName=userName;
    this.password=password;
    this.email=email;

}
```

customer.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "age")
private int age;

 @OneToOne(mappedBy = "customer")
private User user;

public Customer() {
}


public Customer(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

El primer fallo es a nivel de arquitectura, ya que no hay ninguna transacción que englobe los 2 saves. Deberían estar dentro de 1 transacción por el mero hecho de que si falla el segundo save haga 1 rollback de todo.

Por otro lado, estás haciendo 1 save de un new User() y new Customer() en los cuales no les estás pasando las FK respectivas. De hecho estás machacando las variables con la respuesta del save(), por lo que los setters de arriba no se usan.

De la manera que lo tienes, sin transacciones, deberías crear los 2 sin FK y hacer un update informando el setUser() y setCustomer() de lo que te hayan devuelto los saves().